# Functional n-queens

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, chess, n-queens

Following the book "Structure and interpretation of computer programs" I have tried to implement a functional solution to the problem of N-queens (implemented by the function `nQueens`). However, I am not satisfied by the reliance on for loops and the general readability of the code. Could I get your opinion the code?

```
import functools as fn

def safe(positions, k):
    """ Given a list of positions, returns if the queen on the k column
    is safe. """
    enumeratedPos = tuple(enumerate(positions));
    menacesK = fn.partial(menaces, enumeratedPos[k]);
    return not any(map(menacesK,
        filter(lambda pair: pair[0] != k, enumeratedPos)));

def addNewColumn(positions, n):
    """ Given an array of k-length positions maps each position
    to n new k+1-length positions by appending numbers from 0 to n-1 
    Example:
    ((),) -> ((0), (2) ... (n-1))
    ((a),(b)) -> ((a, 0), (a,2) ... (a,n-1), (b,0) ... (b,n-1))
    """
    for position in positions:
        for i in range(0, n):
            yield position + (i,);

def menaces(pair1, pair2):
    colK, rowK = pair1;
    col, row = pair2;
    return abs(rowK - row) == abs(colK - col) or rowK == row;

def nQueens(boardSize):
    """ Given a dimension boardSize, returns a filter with all the solutions to
    n-queens problem where n is boardSize"""
    def recur(i):
        if (i == 0): return ((),);
        safeK = lambda x: safe(x, i-1);
        return filter(safeK, addNewColumn(recur(i-1), boardSize));
    return recur(boardSize);
```

Comment: On the part about for loops, they're basically in every Python program. It's bad to have too many, but don't be shy to show them off.

Comment: shouldn't `menaces` also check whether the queens are in the same column?

Comment: @MaartenFabré Columns are generated by enumerate, so they are necessarily different

Comment: I have no idea how this code works, but it works so :P. I didn't add any optimizations or such as I was slightly scared it was going to `break` '~'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some pretty spicy (nicely formatted) code :)

I'll explain my steps to make it look better and show you the end result. You can follow along and change them while they pop up.

1. Remove the semicolons :P This is Python, not Javascript or C++ or (insert another language). Though they are optional and are perfectly fine to put in, they can cause clutter and reduce readability.
2. All functions and variables should be `lower_case_with_underscores`, classes as `UpperCase`, and constants as `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`. We'll replace them with the correct convention.
3. Replace `map` and `filter` with generator expressions. They may be a bit slower, but it'll be more readable as it resembles normal Python syntax such as the `for` loop and the `if` statement.
4. That recursive function at the bottom can be changed so that it doesn't need that `lambda`. It can make it look nicer without the hidden extra arguments.
5. The top function looks pretty complicated... Here's how to change it so that it doesn't need any variables. The first argument to `menaces` will always be the same, so it can be typed out manually. It's the `k`th item of `enumerate(positions)`, so the argument is `(k, positions[k])`. Note: we can remove the `import functools as fn` line.
6. The second function is a generator function, meaning it returns an iterator. This one is just combining results from two `for` loops. Nested `for` loops are discouraged, so let's replace it with `itertools.product(positions, range(n))`. We'll have to import itertools too. Note: `range(0, n)` is the same as `range(n)`.
7. I've changed the expression of `position + (i,)` to `(*position, i)`. I'm not sure which looks better, but personally the second one resembles the tuple that it yields better than the first.
8. The third function could do with a little makeover. The new variables aren't really needed. I've replaced them with `col_diff` and `row_diff` which store `abs(pair1[n] - pair2[n])` where `n` is `1` for the rows and `0` for the columns. I've also made it explicitly return `True` or `False` and it looks better :)
9. The doc strings also have a convention (for some reason). Single line doc strings can have the triple quotes (`"""`) at the start and end of the line, but multiline doc strings have them on their own lines. Note: I edited the example in `add_new_column` to look like an interactive session that shows how the function works.

Here is the final result:

```py
import itertools


def safe(positions, k):
    """Given a list of positions, return True if the queen on the `k` column is safe."""
    return not any(
        menaces((k, positions[k]), pair)
        for pair in enumerate(positions)
        if pair[0] != k
    )


def add_new_column(positions, n):
    """
    Given an array of k-length `positions`, map each position to `n` new
    k+1-length positions by appending numbers from 0 to `n` - 1.

    >>> list(add_new_column(((),), 3))
    [(0,), (1,), (2,)]
    >>> list(add_new_column(((1,), (2,)), 3))
    [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
    """
    for position, i in itertools.product(positions, range(n)):
        yield (*position, i)


def menaces(pair1, pair2):
    row_diff = abs(pair1[1] - pair2[1])
    col_diff = abs(pair1[0] - pair2[0])
    if row_diff == col_diff:
        return True
    elif pair1[1] == pair2[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def n_queens(board_size):
    """
    Given a dimension `board_size`, return an iterator with all the solutions
    to n-queens problem where n is `board_size`.
    """
    def _recur(i):
        if not i:
            return ((),)
        else:
            return (
                row
                for row in add_new_column(_recur(i - 1), board_size)
                if safe(row, i - 1)
            )
    return _recur(board_size)
```

An extra change I would make is to the `add_new_column` function. It receives the `positions` first which mean that it has to be in a tuple. By moving the `n` parameter to the front and using variable length parameters (`*positions`), the call can look less repetitive.

Here's the new function signature: (You can change the other calls if you like)

```py
def add_new_column(n, *positions):
    """
    Given an array of k-length `positions`, map each position to `n` new
    k+1-length positions by appending numbers from 0 to `n` - 1.

    >>> list(add_new_column(3, ()))
    [(0,), (1,), (2,)]
    >>> list(add_new_column(3, (1,), (2,)))
    [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
    """
    # Here's the code
```

Comment: you can save 1 level of indentation by removing the  `else` in `_recur`. Due to the early `return` in the if-case, this is not needed

Comment: @MaartenFabré I could do that, but I chose not to as it would look weird with all the `return`s in a staircase shape. I added it to make it pop out that it was a choice between the `((),)` and the other thing. I have a little rule set thing: if the `if` leads to an exception being `raise`d, an `else` is not needed; if there are multiple `elif`s, keep the `else`; if there is an early `return` without a value, an else isn't needed. All other cases should have the `else`. +1 for the suggestion tho :)